# How to navigate through wordpress core source and find required .php files to make modifications

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find the wordpress core file that is responsible for displaying the button in the edit post page to allow you to set a featured image. Anyone know the best approach for finding this file? I assume the file would be under wp-admin, but any obviously-named file such as post.php or edit.php doesn't seem to contain this (keeping in mind that strings might not be displayed within the .php, I'm searching for tag id's, such as *set-post-thumbnail*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, on Windows you can grab a trial version of [Powergrep](http://www.powergrep.com/), or use the Windows Powershell command *findstr*:

`findstr /s /i /C:"set-post-thumbnail" *.*`

Assuming you have changed directories to the Wordpress directory.